# Bootstrap Tooltips, how to use a fixed with with alignment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve what on subject, so a tooltip with fixed width, and with right alignment basing on my relative parent. I don't understand the logic, if I set min-width to 100%, the width looks like the 50% of the parent div and if I change it I obtain two undesired behaviours:

1) The tooltip is going outside the parent div (in my case right side)

2) If I change the absolute position of the tooltip class (not the inner one) I can obtain what I want, but the tooltip-arrow element is not correctly aligned anymore (tried to change the position of the class tooltip-arrow but without success, even if with !important on the right value !)

Do you have any hints or a best practice to suggest? Here my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrFabio80/L8cwxqby/13/)

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">col 1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-custom">
           <div class="pull-right">col 2</div>
           <!-- data-container="body"  data-placement="top"  -->
           <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg m-t-xl" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">col 3</div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Css:

```
  .col-custom {
     border: 1px solid black;
     position: relative;
  }
  .tooltip-inner {
     min-width: 100%;
     max-width: 70%;
  }
  .fa-info-circle {
     position: absolute;
     right: 5px;
     top: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: Just set `placement: 'right'` in your jquery instead of `placement: 'top'`:https://jsfiddle.net/L8cwxqby/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this in CSS. You are not setting the tooltips width and positioning.

```
.tooltip{
  width:100%;
  left:0 !important;
  right:0  !important;
}
```

And if you want the right alignment, add this.

```
  .tooltip{
     width:100%;
     right:100%  !important;
  }
```

JS for right alignment

```
$('i[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'right'
});
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, it's very helpful...and the exact alignment I wanted! But now I have the arrow which is not aligned (on top of my i element)

Comment: You can some margin to the icon or try adding some right padding in  .col-custom

Comment: No I meant the arrow, I applied your hint to this new fiddle and I can't align the arrow now -> https://jsfiddle.net/MrFabio80/L8cwxqby/33/     Any idea?

Comment: Add this and you are done :)
 .tooltip-arrow {
   
   right: 7px !important;
   left:auto !important;
 }

Comment: You're an angel:-)